# Java - Check to see if one image contains another

Tags: java, image, loops, bufferedimage

I have this code to do so:

```
for (int hX = 0; hX <= haystack.getWidth() - needle.getWidth(); hX ++) {
    for (int hY = 0; hY <= haystack.getHeight() - needle.getHeight(); hY ++) {
        placement: for (int nX = 0; nX < needle.getWidth(); nX ++) {
            for (int nY = 0; nY < needle.getHeight(); nY ++) {
                if (haystack.getRGB(nX + hX, nY + hY) != needle.getRGB(nX, nY)) {
                    break placement;
                }
            }
            return new Point(hX, hY);
        }
    }
}
return null;
```

But no matter if the image contains the other or not, it always returns null. I don't understand why, because I think this code is accurate. Could someone point out to me what I'm doing wrong, or suggest an alternative way of determining if a larger image contains a smaller image?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: The debugging has led me nowhere. For some reason, it doesn't even seem to be running the loops.

Comment: Then your condition must be false at some point. Have you used the debugger to inspect values at various points in your code?

Comment: I see an accepted answer... but what is the actual problem and solution then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is strange that this method is always returning null, because this algorithm will return the Point as soon as it sees that the first row of pixels of the needle matches some part of the haystack. Consider using a continue statement or using flags and modifying the loop conditions.

There is probably some other reason that it always returns null. Make sure that you aren't getting the needle and haystack mixed up and that some section of the haystack actually contains the exact same RGB values as the needle.

You should make some small test cases too. For example if the needle and haystack are the same, then it should always return a (0, 0) Point.